# callback when all $q promises are resolved

Tags: angularjs, q

With jQuery I can do like that:

```
$.when.apply($, promisesArray).done(function () {});
```

Now that I'm using angular and its service `$q` is there any way I can achieve the same with its promise's implemenation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) is your method

```
$q.all(promisesArray).then(function(results) {});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I don't event know whose answer to accept :). I'll accept yours and upvote Amir's.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
$q.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(){
    // do your stuff.
});
```